# Passing chars from structs through sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, char

I am trying to send/receive messages between my server and client. I currently have a stuct in my server that holds a char value. I am trying to pass this value to my client. See the following:

```
tileInfo->tiles[user_cords_x][user_cords_y].identifier = '+'; // Char i want to pass
write_client_msg(cli_sockfd, &tileInfo->tiles[user_cords_x][user_cords_y].identifier);

/* Writes a message to a client socket. */
void write_client_msg(int cli_sockfd, char * msg)
{
    int n = write(cli_sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing msg to client socket");

}
```

On my client side i am receiving it with the following:

```
char *msg;
char identity = read(sockfd, msg, 1);
printf("This is the value: %d \n", identity);
```

Currently the output i am getting is `This is the value: 1`. I am new to sockets and dont fully understand passing chars. Could someone please explain and show me how to pass the '+' to my client side?

Comment: `read` returns the number of read bytes, not the value it reads. It writes the content into the buffer, which you did not initialize to point to something meaningful.

Comment: Unless you know that the byte in the structure following `.identifier` is a NUL byte your `strlen()` call will return the wrong length.

Comment: You are asking `read()` to receive only 1 byte, that is what the 3rd parameter is for. So that is why its return value is 1.  Also, the return value is an `ssize_t`, not a `char`

Answer (score 1):

You are making several mistakes with your code.

On the server side, in this code:

```
write_client_msg(cli_sockfd, &tileInfo->tiles[user_cords_x][user_cords_y].identifier);
```

It is clear that `identifier` is a single `char`, or else the code would not compile.  In which case, using `strlen()` inside of `write_client_msg()` is wrong, since `msg` will not have a null terminator when passing in a pointer to a single `char`.  You would end up transmitting garbage to the other party, if not just crash altogether from accessing invalid memory.

Then, on the client side, you are passing an uninitialized `msg` pointer to `read()`.  But also, you are displaying `read()`'s return value, which is the number of bytes actually received.  That is why your display is showing `1`, since you are asking for 1 byte to be received.

To send and receive the `identifier` correctly, you would need something more like this instead:

```
void write_client_msg(int sockfd, char *msg, size_t msg_len)
{
    int n = write(sockfd, msg, msg_len);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing msg to client socket");
}

...

write_client_msg(cli_sockfd, &tileInfo->tiles[user_cords_x][user_cords_y].identifier, 1);
```

```
char identity;
int n = read(sockfd, &identity, 1);
if (n < 0)
    error("ERROR reading identity from client socket");
else if (n == 0)
    error("DISCONNECTED while reading identity from client socket");
else
    printf("This is the value: %c \n", identity);
```

That being said, a better solution is to make `write_client_msg()` send the `msg_len` before sending the `msg`.  Especially since `write_client_msg()` doesn't know what kind of data it is sending.  Then the client can read the `msg_len` to know how many bytes to read for the `msg`, and then process the `msg` as needed.

Also, `write()` and `read()` can return fewer bytes than requested, so you need to call them in loops to make sure you actually send/receive everything.

For example:

```
int write_all(int sockfd, void *data, size_t data_len)
{
    char *d = (char*) data;
    while (data_len > 0)
    {
        int n = write(sockfd, d, data_len);
        if (n < 0)
            return n;
        d += n;
        data_len -= n;
    }
    return 1;
}

void write_client_msg(int sockfd, char *msg, size_t msg_len)
{
    uint32_t len = htonl(msg_len);
    int n = write_all(sockfd, &len, sizeof(len));
    if (n == 1)
        n = write_all(sockfd, msg, msg_len);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing msg to client socket");
}

...

write_client_msg(cli_sockfd, &tileInfo->tiles[user_cords_x][user_cords_y].identifier, 1);
```

```
int read_all(int sockfd, void *data, size_t data_len)
{
    char *d = (char*) data;
    while (data_len > 0)
    {
        int n = read(sockfd, d, data_len);
        if (n <= 0)
            return n;
        d += n;
        data_len -= n;
    }
    return 1;
}

char *read_server_msg(int sockfd)
{
    uint32_t len;
    int n = read_all(sockfd, &len, sizeof(len));
    if (n <= 0)
        return NULL;
    len = ntohl(len);
    char *msg = malloc(len+1);
    if (!msg)
        return NULL;
    n = read_all(sockfd, msg, len);
    if (n <= 0) {
        free(msg);
        return NULL;
    }
    msg[len] = '\0';
    return msg;
}

...

char *msg = read_server_msg(sockfd);
if (!msg)
    error("ERROR reading msg from client socket");
else {
    printf("This is the value: %s \n", msg);
    free(msg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The proper solution (based on your code) would be:

```
char *msg;
msg = malloc(2);
if (read(sockfd, msg, 1)!=1) {
    printf("Something wrong\n");
    return 0;
}
msg[1]= '\0';
printf("Sent received: %s \n", msg);
```

Comment: why not `char msg[2]` instead of that expensive malloc?

Comment: @Alnitak, many more possibilities but this user must learn what his/her errors are, so I am only fixing his/her code and not giving other possible solutons.

Comment: The OP's code is not sending a null-terminator, and this code is not null-terminating the received `msg` before displaying it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ah...yes. Fixed.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I would have gotten rid of `malloc()` and used `%c` instead.  Or at least used `%.1s` instead of appending a null terminator.  But whatever works.

Answer (score -3):

Solved:

```
char *msg;
msg = (char*) malloc (1);
read(sockfd, msg, 1);
printf("Sent received: %s \n", msg);
```

Comment: It's almost never necessary to malloc a single byte.   You've also not done anything to ensure that the sent string is NUL terminated.

Comment: Instead you could just use `char msg;` to reserve space on the stack for the data and then pass `&msg` instead of `msg` to the `read()` call.

Comment: No, this is all wrong. You allocate 1 byte but a _string_ of one char requires 2 bytes because of the terminating nul character. You also _must_ check the return value of `read` to know whether it read anything at all.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie to be fair, it's unclear from the posted code whether `.identifier` is actually just a single char or a string of them.   We'd need to see the structure definition to be sure.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Given the direct assignment of a single char to `.identifier` (rather than to `identifier[0]`) then I believe it's really not a string at all.

Comment: @Alnitak The OP's code is passing `&identifier` to `write_client_msg()`, so it is clear that `identifier` is a single `char` or it would not compile. In which case, the use of `strlen()` is wrong.